# DGRID - give numeric value for multiple Characters in field

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

**6.30.15 - HOW CAN I MAKE THIS QUESTION BETTER AND MORE HELPFUL TO OTHERS? FEEDBACK WOULD BE HELPFUL. THANKS!**

I'm still rather new to Dgrid, Dojo, Javascript - really all of it. **In a dgrid cell - there is a value '----------------!!!-'** Or variations of the same format. There might be 1 exclamation point or multiple - and in multiple combinations.

I need to ***get the count of each exclamation point starting FROM THE LEFT.*** For instance - in my example above - those are items 2,3, and 4. I need 2,3 and 4 to display in the dgrid cell grid - not the string above.

Does anyone have any clue how to do this?? I can use a formatter - but this becomes tricky when I have multiple items in the string and different combinations. Any advice or leads in the right direction would be helpful.!

UPDATE with code example: 6.16.15

This works great as long as there is only one exclamation mark. It's the multiple combinations. I'm learning javascript on the fly so part of problem is not knowing exactly how to ask the right questions when researching for an answer.

```
function XXXXInfoFormatter(item){
                //console.log(item,typeof(item));
                var newItem;
                if ( item == '--------------------' ) 
                    newItem = 'No Faults'
                else if ( item == '-------------------!' )
                    newItem = 'XXXX 1'
                else if ( item == '------------------!-' )
                    newItem = 'XXXX 2'
                else if ( item == '-----------------!--' )
                    newItem = 'XXXX 3'
                else if ( item == '----------------!---' )
                    newItem = 'XXXX 4'
                else if ( item == '---------------!----' )
                    newItem = 'XXXX 5'
                else if ( item == '--------------!-----' )
                    newItem = 'XXXX 6'
                else if ( item == '-------------!------' )
                    newItem = 'XXXX 7'
                else if ( item == '------------!-------' )
                    newItem = 'XXXX 8'
                else if ( item == '-----------!--------' )
                    newItem = 'XXXX 9'
                else if ( item == '----------!---------' )
                    newItem = 'XXXX 10'
                else if ( item == '---------!----------' )
                    newItem = 'XXXX 11'
                else if ( item == '--------!-----------' )
                    newItem = 'XXXX 12'
                else if ( item == '-------!------------' )
                    newItem = 'XXXX 13'
                else if ( item == '------!-------------' )
                    newItem = 'XXXX 14'
                else if ( item == '-----!--------------' )
                    newItem = 'XXXX 15'
                else if ( item == '----!---------------' )
                    newItem = 'XXXX 16'
                else if ( item == '---!----------------' )
                    newItem = 'XXXX 17'
                else if ( item == '--!-----------------' )
                    newItem = 'XXXX 18'
                else if ( item == '-!------------------' )
                    newItem = 'Head 19'
                else if ( item == '!-------------------' )
                    newItem = 'XXXX 20'
                else if ( item == '!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!' )
                    newItem = 'All Fault'



         return newItem;

    }
```

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?  This seems like a general JavaScript algorithm question.  Also, based on your description I think you meant from the right, not left?

Comment: Yes from the right -- it reads backwards. Sorry dyslexic moment. :) I'll update my question with the code I've used so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altered.

```
function XXXXInfoFormatter(item) {
    var length = item.length;
    var i;
    var Wrongs = [];

    // Scan chars from right to left.
    for (i = length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if ('!' === item[i]) {
            // If its a '!', put it id from Right to the Wrong list.
            Wrongs.push(length - i);
        }
    }
    // Check if the item is no faults or all faults.
    var wlength = Wrongs.length;
    if (wlength === 0) {
        return 'No Faults';
    } else if (wlength === length) {
        return 'All Faults';
    }

    // Form a Result str from wrong list.
    var str = 'XXXX in: ';

    for (i = 0; i < wlength; ++i) {
        str += ' ' + Wrongs[i] ;
    }
    return str;
}
```

Hope this is what you need.

Comment: You're brilliant!!! I don't know that I ever would have come up with that... at least not anytime soon. Works like a charm! Thank you!!!!

Comment: Glad it helped. But I suggest learning more about javascript before write code for 
current task, unless its urgent. After all, urgently works will make you feel like hell when you watch it later, especially when refactoring it. ; )

Comment: I'm trying to learn it on the fly, among a few other languages for a development project at work. Which isn't very practical or easy. Thanks again so much!

Comment: I've been researching the javascript - trying to reverse the order. For our machinery he said he set the code to read from left to right to make it easier. So I've got to reverse the algorithm that you gave me. I see the top line that says "scan chars from right to left" - I can reverse that right? But to make sure I understand the statement ; for = length of item minus 1; if i is greater than or = 0 then converts to a negative number... is that correct? I've tried reversing it, but no success - any suggestions?

Comment: `for (i = length - 1; i >= 0; --i)` means: we start with `i`'s value equal to `length - 1`, and if `i` is greater or equal to 0, we'll go into the block, each time the block's code is complete, we minus the `i`'s value by 1 (`--i` means `i = i - 1`), so it'll  start from the tail of the word, scan left to check if the checked word is `"!"`, if it is, put length - i (As the right most error in a word with length 20 is marked as 0, not 20), and keep looping until it mets the left end.

Comment: So if you want to scan from left to right, then it'll be `for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)`, means start at word's position 0(left end), and loop to right end, each time the i will move right by 1 (as `++i` is equal to  `i = i + 1`) and still, if the right most error is still marked as `0`, then the index can still remain `length - i`, but as now the error number is from big to small, if you want to keep ascending order, you have to put new wrong index (the smaller) to the front of the array, so it would be changed to `Wrongs.unshift(length - i);`

Comment: Thank you! I was close on the first part- but missed the ascending order part. Thank you. I'm trying to learn the javascript as I go - it's rather complicated it seems, but maybe just because I'm still kind of new to it.